# Get latest assets added to structure

Tags: entries, assets, elementcriteriamodel

I have a structure which is  basically categories of Downloads.
In each Entry there is an "Files" field where multiple assets can be selected.

[image: Downloads]

On a Summary page I want to display the latest assets added.
How can I pull these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as passing `dateCreated` into the `order` parameter, like so:

`{% set downloads = entry.files.order( 'dateCreated desc' ) %}`

If you're showing these from multiple entries you'd need to get all assets that relate to those entries and then order them as above. Something like:

`{% set downloads = craft.assets.relatedTo( entries ).order( 'dateCreated desc' ) %}`

Comment: Excellent - I'd literally just found it out a few minmutes ago by doing more searching on here. Your answer is 100%.
{% set content = craft.entries.section('repository').find() %}
{% set latestfiles = craft.assets.relatedTo(content).order('dateUpdated desc').limit(10) %}